# term colors with solarized scheme

Tags: vim

I am having trouble figuring out how to set the colors for the built-in terminal (i.e. when I run `:term` inside vim). I am using solarized as my main vim colorscheme. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6v8M4.png) of what the terminal colors look like. I would like to have it use the same colorscheme as solarized, or even regular terminal colors (black bg with white fg) is fine. I tried to use `:set termguicolors` but this broke the color scheme of the vim panes (although it did make the terminal pane look normal). I am not very familiar with the vim internals so I might be doing something wrong. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is no screenshot

Comment: @Jorengarenar Apologies. Added screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured it out:

I added the following line in my vimrc and it fixed the problem:

```
hi Terminal ctermbg=black ctermfg=white guibg=black guifg=white
```

See the new [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvCT4.png)!